# Custom module created in CE is installing on pro 6.7.1 but not showing in menu

Tags: sugarcrm

I created a custom module in CE exported it and done some custom coding in it. It installs and works on the current version of CE and works on pro 6.5.14. But in pro 6.7.1 it will install and works but it does not show up in the menu anywhere. I am giving the module to a client that is using 6.7.1 pro on demand and I also have a local copy of their instance which it still wont display in the menu.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem buy adding the code below in /custom/include/language/en_us.lang.php

$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['moduleList']['module_name'] = 'label_name';

But is this a known sugar bug? Since you wouldn't normally have to add that line in manually.